# Is URLSession supported on Linux?

Tags: swift, linux

On trying to access the Oxford dictionary api using swift on Linux I find a roadblock. It may be some mistake I am doing, but I can't identify what it is. At this point I suspect is something related to the base OS. So please consider the bash code:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: text/plain' --header 'app_id: 8a7dd147' --header 'app_key: 7e7d022fbce6d8d4523eac3baa5bd04c' 'https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/en/ace'
```

Which returns json data for the word Ace. Now, on Ubuntu 18.04 I try the following:

```
import Foundation
//var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/en/love")!)

// TODO: replace with your own app id and app key
let appId = "8a7dd147"
let appKey = "7e7d022fbce6d8d4523eac3baa5bd04c"
let language = "en"
let word = "Ace"
let word_id = word.lowercased() //word id is case sensitive and lowercase is required
let url = URL(string: "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/en/love")!  // \(language)/\(word_id)")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.addValue(appId, forHTTPHeaderField: "app_id")
request.addValue(appKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "app_key")
//request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
print("passed request addValue")

let session = URLSession.shared
_ = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
    if let response = response,
        let data = data,
        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) {
            print("about to give you a response")
        print(response)
        print(jsonData)
    } else {
        print(error)
        print(NSString.init(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
    }
}).resume()
```

Or the following:

```
import Foundation

let params: [String: String] = ["app_id": "8a7dd147", "app_key": "7e7d022fbce6d8d4523eac3baa5bd04c"]

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/en/love")!)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.addValue("8a7dd147", forHTTPHeaderField: "app_id")
request.addValue("7e7d022fbce6d8d4523eac3baa5bd04c", forHTTPHeaderField: "app_key")

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
    print(response!)
    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)
        print(json)
        print("we did it!")
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
}).resume()

//task.resume()
```

But none returns the json information for the word "love". I have been trying to debug this and can't figure out what is wrong.

- Is it OS related, thus a bug? Could someone test it on MacOS. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Tried it on macOS as a separate Swift file, and I get nothing. When I added the following line `sleep(10)` to allow 10 seconds before the program ends, it made results.  So, if you embed it in code for making a web service or backend, you should try to apply asynchronous programming (where you respond to events, not do something then another). And if you are just making a proof of concept, you may replace the URLSession by using `Data(contentsOf:)` where you load synchronously, or just wait for the result by any safe means.

Comment: Yep, this seems to be the issue, will look into async for api requests, thanks. Perhaps you could convert your comment into an answer so I can accept. All the best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`URLSession` executes things on background threads. And when you end the main thread of a multithreaded program, all of the threads are terminated (except that i n some languages like Java you can set the Daemon thread, which may be some other thread but ending the program would be after the end of that thread instead).

So, your solution is to extend the lifetime of your main thread, like:

```
let group = DispatchGroup.init()

group.enter() // Use this before making anything that needs to be waited for
              // This manually add one to operation count in the dispatch group
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
    defer {  // Defer makes all ends of this scope make something, here we want to leave the dispatch.
             // This is executed when the scope ends, even if with exception.


       group.leave() // Manually subtract one from the operation count
    }
    print(response!)
    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)
        print(json)
        print("we did it!")
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
}).resume()

group.wait()  // Wait for group to end operations.
```

But the better, is that you don't block the main thread in real life applications, like web applications for example, your application normally lives more than the requests, so you wouldn't need to interfere, but try to avoid blocking the user (`sleep`,  `DispatchGroup.wait` except if in background thread, etc...)

Comment: Using `sleep()` on the main thread is a very bad idea. Your second idea of dispatch groups is much, MUCH better. You should edit your answer and delete the sleep option. That's bad advice

Comment: Thanks, it is very useful for CLI tool

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this code:

```
// Avoid closing this project for 40 seconds
RunLoop.main.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 40))
```